# Is there a better way to count nested arrays in an object using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a deep object with nested arrays, which looks something like this:

```
{
   inspectionReport: {
     property: {
       structures: [
         {
           finishedSpaces: [
             {
               levels: [
                 {
                   rooms: [
                     //something I want to count
                   ]
                 }
               ]
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to find the total length of all the `rooms` arrays. The most obvious way is this:

```
let roomCount = 0;

results['inspectionReport']['property']['structures'].forEach(structure => {
  structure['finishedSpaces'].forEach(finishedSpace => {
    finishedSpace['levels'].forEach(level => {
      roomCount += level['rooms'].length;
    });
  });
});
```

But that seems a little ugly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: this syntax looks weird to me : `structures: [0: { ....`

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava - It's an object with a nested array of objects, and those objects have their own arrays.

Comment: I see but this: ` [0:` syntax I haven't seen (inside array)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: It's not valid JS object syntax, normally you'd omit the `0:`. I just put it in to emphasize where the arrays are.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava - Edited to make it valid JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like below, using [`sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy).

```
const totalRooms = _.sumBy(inspectionReport.property.structures, structure =>
  _.sumBy(structure.finishedSpaces, finishedSpace =>
    _.sumBy(finishedSpace.levels, level =>
      level.rooms.length
    )
  )
);

console.log(totalRooms);
```

The solution you provided using forEach is straightforward and easy to understand. The above solution is more concise and functional. so up to you to decide.

Also, you can look into a solution where you flatten up to the `levels` array and use `sumBy()`,

```
const totalRooms = _.sumBy(
  _.flatMap(results['inspectionReport']['property']['structures'], 'finishedSpaces.levels'),
  'length'
);
```

ps: you may have to double-check the above codes, I haven't tested it.

Comment: I don't think your `flatMap` solution is quite right, since `finishedSpaces` is an array, but it's very close. Accepting because it's close enough to what I'm looking for.